# big O inequality

Tags: asymptotics

In $e^{-\omega/\epsilon}\leq10^{-9}$ why is $\omega=O(\epsilon)$ and in $e^{-\omega/\epsilon}\leq \epsilon$ why is $\omega=O(\epsilon\ln1/\epsilon)$ where $\epsilon$ is a very small parameter.

Comment: Are you sure that the direction of the inequalities are correct? It seems to me that for the first one $\omega\in\Omega(\epsilon)$ as $\omega \geq (9\log 10)\epsilon$.

Comment: @Lord Soth, yes am sure.

Comment: LordSoth was trying to be polite: the first inequality **does not** imply $\omega=O(\epsilon)$ and the second inequality **does not** imply $\omega=O(\epsilon\log1/\epsilon)$. What is your source?

Comment: @Did here is the book, http://www.amazon.com/Numerical-Methods-Singular-Perturbation-Problems/dp/9814390739 Chapter 2 page 7

Comment: Vaulter, if you read closely it says "the width of the boundary layer [...] is the smallest value $\omega$ such that $e^{-\omega/\epsilon} \leq 10^{-9}$", which is $\omega = (9\log 10)\epsilon$.  This is indeed $O(\epsilon)$.  Similarly for the second inequality.  It's not true that all $\omega$ which satisfy $e^{-\omega/\epsilon} \leq 10^{-9}$ are $O(\epsilon)$ (for example take $\omega = (9\log 10)\sqrt{\epsilon}$), but the smallest one, the one you care about, certainly is.

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'll post [my comment above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433819/big-o-inequality#comment929939_433819) as an answer since it seems to address what the OP was looking for.)

In the [reference given](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433819/big-o-inequality#comment929756_433819) for the source of this question it states

> The width of the boundary layer [...] could be taken to be the smallest value $\omega$ such that $e^{-\omega/\epsilon} \leq 10^{-9}$, say.  In this case it is clear that $\omega = O(\epsilon)$.

As shown in [this related answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/434494/5531), the smallest such $\omega$ is $\omega = (9\log 10)\epsilon$, which is indeed $O(\epsilon)$.

It's not true that all $\omega$ which satisfy $e^{-\omega/\epsilon} \leq 10^{-9}$ are $O(\epsilon)$ (for example take $\omega = (9\log 10)\sqrt{\epsilon}$), but the smallest one, the one you care about, certainly is.  Dealing with the other inequality is similar.