# Asymptotic solutions for inequalities

Tags: perturbation-theory

How do I determine the order (big o) of $\omega$ in $e^{-\omega/\epsilon}\leq10^{-9}$ and $e^{-\omega/\epsilon}\leq\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is a small parameter.

Comment: Hi, I remember you asking this question yesterday http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433819/big-o-inequality, and I remember telling you that in fact there is no big $O$ of omega but indeed $\omega \in \Omega(\epsilon)$. Did has followed up and you told him that you found this in a book. Why don't you scan or (just write) that part of the book so that we can understand where the problem lies and help you resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, taking logs yields
$$-\omega/\epsilon \leq -9 \ln(10)\\
\omega \geq 9 \epsilon \ln(10)\\
\omega = \Omega(\epsilon)$$
and similarly in the second case $\omega \geq \epsilon \ln (\epsilon)$ so $\omega = \Omega(\epsilon\ln (\epsilon))$